# mysql. вызов процедуры с параметрам ID

Tags: php, mysqli, процедуры

Доброго времени суток ...
Не получается выполнение процедуры. Подскажите как длелать выборку новости по ее ID.

```
 $query = "CREATE PROCEDURE `post` (IN id INT(11)) 
 LANGUAGE SQL DETERMINISTIC 
 SQL SECURITY DEFINER COMMENT 'select post' 
 BEGIN SELECT * FROM `cute_news` JOIN `cute_story` USING(`id`) WHERE `id` = id OR `url` = id;
 END";

 $query = mysqli_query ($query);
 $query = mysqli_query("CALL post($id)");
 $row   = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
 echo $row['title'];
```

Код выдает всегда только первый пост с ID  =1

Comment: А не лучше ли использовать только сам SELECT? и при использование всё ли работает так как нужно?

Comment: Работает ... но выдаёт только первый пост с ID =1 , т.е не реагирует на переменную $id

Comment: Я имел в виду ваш 'SELECT * FROM `cute_news` JOIN `cute_story` USING(`id`) WHERE `id` = id OR `url` = id' работает, так как нужно? То есть реагирует ли на `id`? Если возврат только ID =1 значить он он работает

Comment: Да . сам по себе (чистый запрос) работает как нужно  (уже лет 5 ) =)

Comment: Тогда, точно не уверен, попробуйте (IN id INT(11) поменайте название входящего параметра, и еще, присвойте его данный другой переменной через SET, может поможет

Comment: _никогда_ не называйте параметры процедуры так же как называется хотя бы одна колонка в таблице. вы думаете, что MySQL может разобраться где какой id в условии `WHERE `id` = id`  - это не так, он использует только один из них. ПЕРЕИМЕНУЙТЕ параметр. И еще у вас всего один fetch, значит вы обрабатываете заведомо только 1 строку результата

Comment: перепробовал все , перегуглил кучу форумов.

Comment: "никогда не называйте параметры процедуры так же как называется хотя бы одна колонка в таблице" .... ага попробую....

Comment: Mike ! Да ! =)))))

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение:

```
$query = "CREATE PROCEDURE `post` (IN post INT(11)) 
LANGUAGE SQL DETERMINISTIC 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
COMMENT 'выделить один пост по ID' 
BEGIN 
SET @id = post;
SELECT * FROM `news` JOIN `story` USING(`id`) WHERE `id`=post OR `url`=post;
END";
$query = mysqli_query ($query);


$post = mysqli_query("CALL post($id)");
$post = isset($id) ? reset($post) : [];

var_dump($post);
```

Так ... но почему-то пропадают другие SQL запросы